# How can I modify Wagner Whitin algorithm to construct an algorithm where the decision is whether or not to order in a given period

Tags: dynamic-programming

i.e. among N time periods the no. of setups should not exceed any k.

By using dynamic forward equations

Our Wagner Whithin method is this:
Let
St setup cost in period t
Yt a binary variable that assumes value 1 if the product
is produced in period t and 0, otherwise
Ct variable unit production cost in period t
Xt production amount in period t
ht unit inventory holding cost in period t (usually constant
for all t)
It inventory at the end of period t

Minimise Z = Summation (t=1 to T)(StYt + CtXt + htIt)
Subject to Xt + It−1 − It = dt (t = 1;:::;T);
Yt ∈ {0; 1} (t = 1;:::;T)
Xt<=0 
It>=0 (t = 1;:::;T):

Now if a extra constraint is put saying no. of setups must is less than any k How can I reconstruct above algorithm?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you get an answer if you show us that you made some effort.

Comment: The effort should be part of the question, not a comment.